# Simulating rolling dice on a dynamic webpage using Bash

Tags: linux, bash, cgi, debian

I'm currently working on a Bash script that simulates rolling a number of 6-sided dice. This is all taking place within a virtual machine running Debian that's acting as a server. Essentially, my webpage simulates rolling the dice by using the query string to determing the number of dice to be rolled.

For instance, if my URL is `http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/rolldice.sh?6`, I want the webpage to say "You rolled 6 dice" and then, on the next line, print six numbers between 1 and 6 inclusive (that are of course "randomly" generated).

Currently, printing out the "You rolled x dice" header is working fine. However, I'm having trouble with the next part. I'm very new to Bash, so possibly the syntax or something similar is wrong with my loop. Here it is:

```
for i in {1..$QUERY_STRING }; do
      dieRoll = $(( $RANDOM % 6 + 1))
      echo $dieRoll
done
```

Can anyone help me figure out where I'm going wrong? I'll be happy to post the rest of `rolldice.sh` if needed.

Comment: you can't put variables inside `{x..y}`.

Comment: Then how should I go about implementing the counting loop?

Answer (score 0):

Since `..` requires its arguments to be literals, you have to use `eval` to substitute the variable:

```
for i in $(eval "echo {1..$QUERY_STRING}"); do
```

Or if you have the `seq` command, you can do:

```
for i in $(seq 1 "$QUERY_STRING")
```

I recommend the latter -- using `eval` with input from the user is very dangerous.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! However, out of curiosity: why is it "dangerous" to use `eval` when dealing with user input?

Comment: @aricha1940 Suppose the user supplies input containing `; rm *`

Comment: Rather than use `eval`, it would probably be faster to use the bash for loop arithmetic construct: `for ((i=1; i<=$QUERY_STRING; i++))`